# Why won't my php code "unlink" text files?

Tags: php, unlink

I have two text files, and a PHP script intended to delete them. My question is: why won't the two text files delete? They are both set to 777, maybe i should change permission settings? I think it's my webhost disallowing the function to execute...

Here is my code: http://informationalinformation.info/fg/cron.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process must have write permission for the folder in which the file is located.

Comment: yup you got it, it was the folder not being 777ed either.